# Differences between set and setRepeat methods of AlarmManager class?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Can anyone tell the differences between set and setRepeat methods of AlarmManager class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, set will create an alarm that will only go off once at a certain time, useful for a specific event.

setRepeating will go off initially at a specific time and continue to go off every period of time. There is an extra argument to specify the length of the interval between subsequent alarms. This is useful for something that will need to be updated/run multiple times, say each day.